# Mongoose getter / setters for normalizing data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, normalization

I have `User` schema which has a `username` field. I would like this field to be case sensitive, so that users may register names such as `BobDylan`. However, I need my schema to validate new entries to check there are no duplicates, incase sensitive, such as `bobdylan`.

My research has taught me that I should create an additional field in the schema for storing a lower case / upper case version, so that I can easily check if it is unique. My question is, how would I achieve this with the Mongoose API?

I have tried using a `set` function, such as:

```
UserSchema.path('username_lower_case').set(function(username_lower_case) {
  return this.username.toLowerCase()
});
```

However, this function doesn't seem to be running. I basically need to tell `username_lower_case` to be whatever `username` is, but in lower case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way would be to use a pre-save hook to do it.

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.username_lower_case = this.username && this.username.toLowerCase();
    next();
});
```

Another way would be to make `username` a virtual:

```
UserSchema.virtual('username').set(function (value) {
    this.username_raw = value;
    this.username_lower_case = value && value.toLowerCase();
}).get(function () {
    return this.username_raw;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Does pre save happen before validation?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think when you call `save`, the validation hooks run before the `pre-save` hooks. At least, that would make the most sense.